# Inserting buttons into Popover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to insert 2 buttons into popover which is triggered by .clear-history button:

```
<div class="modal-footer text-nowrap">
    <button type="button" class="clear-history btn btn-link">Clear history</button>
</div>
```

---

```
const clearHistoryBtn = `
    <span>All records will be removed</span>
    <button type="button" class="confirm-clear-history btn btn-sm btn-danger">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link">No</button>
`;
$('.clear-history').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    title: 'You are cleaning the history',
    content: clearHistoryBtn
});
```

But only text inside the popover:

[image]

I wonder if it has something to do with the modal

---

Update:

[image]

Where goes the rest part of my content???

I didn't set any css like display:none or .hide() or visibility: hidden or removeClass() or etc. to any button

Comment: I was able to get it to work in this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ab103ope/. Maybe there is some JS/CSS that is interfering? Any errors in your console?

Comment: @Jon Lambson The only difference between ours is I put it in the footer while you put it in the body

Comment: @Jon Lambson And I don't get any errors in the console

Comment: @Jon Lambson Check my update, plz!

Comment: Have a look of this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001921/popover-html-content-with-button-and-input-not-rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in this way, working example given below:

```js
const clearHistoryBtn = `
    <span>All records will be removed</span>
    <button type="button" class="confirm-clear-history btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="alert('event raised from yes button');">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link" onclick="alert('event raised from no button');">No</button>
`;

$('.clear-history').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    title: 'You are cleaning the history',
    content: clearHistoryBtn
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal-footer text-nowrap">
    <button type="button" class="clear-history btn btn-link">Clear history</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working. I cannot see the buttons so the alerts not popping up

Comment: But it's working here, you check the same via hitting the Run code snippet. If it's not working in your code then it might have an script order issue or any other css, script conflict issue in your code. Can you share the error that you are getting or order of your scripts.

Comment: No errors. This script is right after those libs src with $(document).ready

Comment: ok. Then only reason behind this is the other css that interfere with bootstrap and changing the UI for the popover. Can you comment the other css or the custom one that you are using just to see the output or find out the reason.